# Posemode: Rotating a bone around something else than its head in pose mode without changeing its relations?

Tags: bones

I have got a rigged character, which author has put the head of the jaw bone to anatomically wrong position.

I don't want to re-rig the head, the jaw the mouth and so on to fix this.

To find a acceptable point around which the jaw bone should rotate I used the 3D-Cursor as pivot point and moved it step by step to an acceptable position.

How can I make the jaw bone rotate around this point permanently (also when animating) without changeing its relation to other bone or to make greater changes to the rig/weight painting?

Comment: hello, I'm not sure what the problem would be if you moved the head of your bone to a new position, maybe share your file or at least a simplified version? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: A new position of the bone would imply, that I need to do new weight painting, what I try to avoid.

Comment: please provide some images or gifs to make the problem clear